# 'if' statements don't function correctly

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I am writing some jQuery code that involves jumping from several functions. In one function, an 'if'-statement is used to select where the code will go next. The condition for the if statement is the value of a variable that was passed from the previous function. So, to clarify, a function passes a variable to another function, which then goes to another function which is chosen based on the function it originated from.

Here is my code in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VFVk7/

As you can see, when you click on any of the buttons, it goes to all of the optional functions from the If-statement, not just one. Does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By writing `if(origin = 'go1')`, you are *assigning* `'go1'` to the `origin` variable, and passing the result of that assignment (which is the string `'go1'`) to the `if` statement.
Since all non-empty strings are "truthful" in Javascript, this is equivalent to `if (true)`, and all of the `if` statements execute.

You need to *compare* `'go1'` to the `origin` variable by writing `if (origin === 'go1')`.

### Summary

- The `=` operator assigns a value to a variable
- The `==` operator performs a loose comparison (eg, `true == '1'`, `8 == '8'`, `16 == '0x10'`, `false == []`).
- The `===` operator performs a strict comparison.  (none of the above examples are true with `===`)

Comment: Thanks very much for all the clarification SLaks!

Answer (score 6):

You have code like

```
if(origin = 'go1')
```

which **assigns** `'go1'` to variable `origin` (and check if that's "true" -- which it is).
Try, instead:

```
if(origin == 'go1')
```

to *compare* instead of *assigning*.

Answer (score -2):

Common problem. In Java it will give a compile error, in Javascript it will work just fine, probably not in the way you want it. `=` sign in Javascript does not perform equality operation.